# Trying to print the values in a 2D array

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, random

As shown from the title, I am trying to print the values of a 2D array. My code is below. I am not sure why my code is not printing the resultant array. As shown below, I am going to make a square matrix, and give the values in it random numbers between 0 and 50. Any ideas will be appreciated. Thank you very much.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () {

    int rows, cols, r, c; 

    printf("Enter the dimension of your square matrix: ");
    scanf("%d", &rows);

    rows=cols; 

    int A[rows][cols]; 

    for (r=0;r<rows;r++){

        for (c=0; c<cols; c++){

            A[r][c]=(rand() % 50); //Generates random number b/w 0 and 50.  

        }



    }

    for (r=0;r<rows;r++){ 

        for (c=0; c<cols; c++){

            printf("%d", A[r][c]);

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What is your code currently doing incorrect?

Comment: Try to format your code correctly.

Comment: I am able to run my code to the point where my code does ask for the dimensions, and I am able to type in a number of my choice. However, it  just does not print the resultant array.  I do not get any error code, and it compiles fine.

Comment: `rows=cols;` But `cols` hasn't been set (`rows` has)...

Answer (score 0):

After the `scanf()` you overwriting the `rows` value.
Switch `rows = cols` to `cols = rows`.

Also you forgot to set the seed of rand ( `srand( time(NULL) )` ).

Your code will look like this:

```
int main(){

int rows, cols, r, c; 
srand(time(NULL));

printf("Enter the dimension of your square matrix: ");
scanf("%d", &rows);

cols=rows; 

int A[rows][cols]; 

for (r=0;r<rows;r++){

    for (c=0; c<cols; c++){

        A[r][c]=(rand() % 50); //Generates random number b/w 0 and 50.  

    }

}

for (r=0;r<rows;r++){ 

    for (c=0; c<cols; c++){

        printf("%d ", A[r][c]);

    }
    printf("\n");
}

}
```